# Web Scraping: Empty / NA / Null entries when running the spider, correct entries in scrapy shell

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

Webscraping a website, I'm making a spider that crawls through the pagination for the newest videos, scraping metadata for each of the 32 videos per page.

Next is my code for the spider:

```py
class NaughtySpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "naughtyspider"
  allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
  max_pages = 3
  # Start request
  def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(1, self.max_pages):
            yield scrapy.Request('https://www.example.com/video?o=cm&page=%s' % i, callback=self.parse_video)
  # First parsing method
  def parse_video(self, response):
    self.log('F i n i s h e d  s c r a p i n g ' + response.url)
    video_links = response.css('ul#videoCategory').css('li.videoBox').css('div.thumbnail-info-wrapper').css('span.title > a').css('::attr(href)') #Correct path, chooses 32 videos from page ignoring the links coming from ads
    links_to_follow = video_links.extract()
    for url in links_to_follow:
      yield response.follow(url = url,
                            callback = self.parse_metadata)
  # Second parsing method
  def parse_metadata(self, response):
    # Create a SelectorList of the course titles text
    video_title = response.css('div.title-container > h1.title > span.inlineFree::text')
    # Extract the text and strip it clean
    video_title_ext = video_title.extract_first()
    # Extract views
    video_views = response.css('span.count::text').extract_first()
    # Extract tags
    video_tags = response.css('div.tagsWrapper a::text').extract()
    # Extract Categories
    video_categories = response.css('div.categoriesWrapper a::text').extract()
    # Fill in the dictionary
    yield {
        'title': video_title_ext,
        'views': video_views,
        'tags': video_tags,
        'categories': video_categories,
    }
```

The thing is that almost half the entries end up being empty, with no title, views, tags or categories. Example of the log:

```
[scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.example.com/view_video.php?viewkey=ph5d594b093f8d6>
{'title': None, 'views': None, 'tags': [], 'categories': []}
```

But at the same time, if I fetch the very same link in the scrapy shell, and copy and paste the very same selector paths in the spider, it gives me the correct values:

```py
In [4]: fetch('https://www.example.com/view_video.php?viewkey=ph5d594b093f8d6')
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.com/view_video.php?viewkey=ph5d594b093f8d6> (referer: None)

In [5]: response.css('div.tagsWrapper a::text').extract()
Out[5]: ['alday', '559', '+ ']

In [6]: response.css('span.count::text').extract_first()
Out[6]: '6'
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edit: Would I be correct in thinking that this is not a problem with my code but rather a limitation on the server to avoid being scraped?**

Comment: It’s possible that you are being detected as a bot, yet, and given a different response. Store the response the spider gets into a file, and compare with the one you get from `scrapy shell`.

Answer (score 0):

The data such as the views, duration, ... seems to be called in by a HTML variable element `<var> DATA </var>`. For example, if you enter the following line in your scrapy shell, you should get the views.

```
response.xpath(".//var[@class='duration')")
```

Not sure if it will work, but it is worth the try.

*P.s. I'll have to tell my wife it was for educational purposes..*

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I follow what you're offering as an answer. The xpath you put is considered invalid syntax, even when I fix the right square bracket. I also do not see where it came from when inspecting the elements on the website. It also does not explain why would my path be wrong in the first place, given that it works in scrapy shell (and for half the entries once crawled). I appreciate your moral sacrifice though.

Comment: <span class="views"><var>113</var> views</span>   This is how I see it when I inspect the element. Mhm.

Comment: I see it as this: <div class="views"> <span class="count">11</span> " views" </div>. Are you looking at the video views from the thumbnail or from the actual video link? The point remains that my problem is not accessing the views, as can be seen from the scrapy shell example in my question.